# Convert vb.net String to Json Object?

Tags: json, vb.net

I am new in vb.net, I am developing a webservice. I want to send a response in a json object.
I have only one string in response.

```
public string GetUser(String IMEI)
{
    string msg = "";
    string SQL1 = "Select Email from [Customer] where [Vehicle]='" + IMEI + "'";
    DataTable dt = dbcom.GetDataTable(SQL1);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        msg = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
        //CV(username, IMEI);
        //vehiclechk(IMEI);
    }
    return msg;
}
```

This send xml string.
How we convert `msg` string in to json.

Comment: Take a look at [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 6):

I guess there are two ways to do it.  Since this is a simple string, you can just brute force it:

```
 Dim jsonMsg = "{""msg"":""" & msg & """}"
```

A more sophisticated way is put it into a class and serialize it.

```
Public Class MyMessage
  Public Property Msg As String
  Public Sub New(myMsg as String)
    Msg = myMsg
  End Sub
End Class

Dim myMsg As New MyMessage(msg)
Dim serializer as new JavaScriptSerializer
Dim jsonMsg = serializer.Serialize(myMsg)
```

You need a reference to System.Runtime.CompilerServices.